# RegEx Issue: Preg_Match Only 2 non consecutive spaces, no special characters [PHP]

Tags: php, regex

So for my class we are simulating someone putting in a first, middle, and last name into a form. I have a variable `$fullname` that concats them and pulls out a middle initial as well as `strtolower` and `ucfirst`...

so `rObERT jAmES smITH` is then parsed as `Robert J Smith`.

Now if someone were to put `R!bert J Smith` (note the special character"`!`") It would be accepted. To combat this i did a `If`/`else` statement with `pregmatch`.

```
if (preg_match("/[^a-z\s]/i",$fullname)) {
        echo ("<span class = 'warning'>Invalid User Name!</span>"."<br>"
                ."Please use only characters A-Z for your name."."<br>");
        exit; 
    }
    else {                   
        echo ("User Name: ".$fullname."<br>"); 
    }
```

This basically says if there is anything besides letters and whitespace, throw my echo message.

Now I have run into the issue if someone was to enter `R obert J Smith`. (Note the space character inbetween `R` and `o`). Because I allow whitespace it says it is okay. This goes on to mess up all my "`create username and password`" functions later on.

TLDR: What I am asking is what will allow the pregmatch to match or not match ONLY 2 nonconsecutive whitespaces and only characters `A-Z/i`

Note: I tried doing various versions of `\s {2}` but that is for consecutive spaces, not non-consecutive spaces.

PS: There will only ever be 2 spaces. I Trim the input before it is parsed into `$fullname` .

I have been trying this for 3 hours now and the frustration is blocking my ability to approach this in a different direction.

Thank You,
thelaughingman

Comment: Count the number of space characters. Check for non-alphanumeric characters (like `!`, but maybe `'` and `\`` are allowed?). Also what about names like _Armin van Buuren_ or _Robert McPhearson_?

Comment: To match 2 non-consecutive spaces you can use `'/\s\S+\s/'` regex.

Comment: It's more complicated than this. What if the name is `Robert James Van Winkle III`? What about `Dr. Robert Van Winkle James, Jr.`? The answers you got will help you, but you need to think about the edge cases. (Note: I realize your assignment may be limited to the simpler cases, so consider this advice for the real-world case, not necessarily for your class.)

Comment: Thank you Ed, I did think about that but the requirements for the assignment just want a standard FN Middle Initial LN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with a regular expression:

```
/^\w+(\s\w+){0,2}$/
```

which matches 1, 2 or 3 space-separated words, or use this to always match 3:

```
/^\w+\s\w+\s\w+$/
```

but you could also split your check for invalid characters (`/[^\w]/`) off from checking the number of words entered:

```
if ( count( explode(' ', $fullname) ) != 3 )
```

Comment: Thank You! I used /^\w+\s\w+\s\w+$/ originally and then ended up replacing \w with [a-z] and /i

Comment: You're welcome! Btw, I'd look into what Ed Cotrell said - detecting middle names is not as straightforward as it looks; the only way to be sure is to have multiple input fields (fname, lname, middle names, title, etc...).. Also, married women often append a hyphen and their maiden name. It's almost as complex as addresses, best to just feed users back the input they gave, as-is..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex for matching your fullname that will allow only 1 or 2 spaces:

```
'/^\p{L}+(?:\h\p{L}+){1,2}$/u'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dV4pY2/2)

`\p{L}` matches any unicode letter and `/u` is to support unicode in regex.

Comment: Thank You! This was way beyond me, I appreciate the link, and I will try to understand it further

    Note: for the assignment our prof told us we didnt need to worry about extra characters, so now i know in the future how to include all unicode letters, thank you :)

Comment: I am really surprised that you removed acceptance mark. The answer you've marked will also validate `123` OR just `_` as a valid name. btw if anything is not clear feel free to ask questions. The demo link I provided has all the details of the regex I've used.